# Why Kotlin online editor throws FileNotFoundException exception?

Tags: kotlin, jetbrains-ide

I am trying to run kotlin code using online editor. However, it throws following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: /var/task/tmp/c2490bcf8f0044b7a1d665799dd03876/executor.policy (No such file or directory)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0 (FileOutputStream.java:-2) 
at java.io.FileOutputStream.open (FileOutputStream.java:270) 
at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init> (FileOutputStream.java:213)
```

[image]

Please let me know how to solve this.

Comment: Raise a support ticket with JetBrains.

Comment: @Dai Thanks. I will do that too!

Comment: They're working on it: https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/unknown-error-in-kotlin-online-editors/23440/7

Comment: @broot thanks. I rather wait until the problem is solved!

Comment: You can just keep trying until it runs - it doesn't always fail (unless it got worse since I last used it!)

Comment: There was a server issue and they have fixed it. Therefore, the issue is solved.